# wkhtmltopdf --enable-forms attribute not displaying textbox value

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I want to convert my HTML to pdf. I am using wkhtmltopdf.

The following is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="text1" type="text" value="Value of the TextBox" />
</body>
</html>
```

The following command line gives me correct output

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe  "file:///D:/Default.html" "d:/test.pdf"
```

[image]

But I want to enable the form. So I am using --enable-forms attribute

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --enable-forms  "file:///D:/Default.html" "d:/test.pdf"
```

[image]

It gives me empty textbox. I want to display the textbox value in the textbox.
I have tried wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 version. Even though I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please give the unique name of each input element.

Got a fix from the below link:
"If you want to create a PDF form all your input elements must have a unique name."
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1784